# Problem with certain Amount of Turtles with a specific Attributes

Tags: netlogo

i've encountered a Problem with my NetLogo Model. While I'm trying to give a certain number of Turtles (here "Akteure") a certain Vallue, which I want to set first constant on 1 (one-of) and later control the amount with a slider, I only revieve random numbers, often higher then for example the one-of limitation I've set in the code below

````
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  set radius max-pxcor - 2
  create-ordered-Akteure number-of-Akteure[
  fd max-pxcor - 5
  rt  90
  set size 3
  set shape "person"
  set color white
  set Information1 false
  set Information2 false
  set Macht_neutral true
  ask one-of Akteure [set information1 true] 
      if Information1 [set color green]
  ask one-of Akteure [set Information2 true]
      if Information2 [set Color Red]
  ask one-of Akteure [set shape "kings"]
    if shape = "Kings" [set Macht_hoch true]
  ask one-of Akteure [set shape "Bauer"]
    if shape = "Bauer" [set Macht_gering true] 
   ]```


What am I ignoring, where is my mistake?

Jan
````

Answer (score 1):

I think one problem is, that you set these values within the `create-ordered-Akteure` block, so that `number-of-Akteure`-times one random Akteur will be set e.g. to Bauer. Just close the block before `ask one-of ...` and join the set code blocks:

```
  create-ordered-Akteure number-of-Akteure
  [
    fd max-pxcor - 5
    rt  90
    set size 3
    set shape "person"
    set color white
    set Information1 false
    set Information2 false
    set Macht_neutral true
  ]
  ask one-of Akteure 
  [
    set information1 true
    set color green
  ]
  ask one-of Akteure 
  [
    set Information2 true
    set Color Red
  ]
  ask one-of Akteure 
  [
    set shape "kings"
    set Macht_hoch true
  ]
  ask one-of Akteure 
  [
    set shape "Bauer"
    set Macht_gering true
  ]
```

I prefere to open a block within a new line, so that I can easily see, which block is closed, but that is probably just a style question